# reverting @extend in SASS

Tags: css, sass, extend

I want to @extend a class in certain conditions and in other conditions to revoke that @extend

```
<div class="myclass">
 <div class="not_special">
</div>
</div>
```

so when there is no .not_special child it would be

```
.myclass
  @extend .special
```

and when there is a .not_special child

```
.myclass:has(.not_special)
  //revoke the previous @extend
```

I can't use javascript to add or remove classes because the events are not clearly defined since there could be many events and catching them all is impossible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to "unextend" a class in SASS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505378/is-there-any-way-to-unextend-a-class-in-sass)

Answer (score 5):

Use `:not` pseudoclass

```
.myclass:not:has(.not_special)
    @extend .special
```

This will apply the `@extend` to all `.myclass`except when they have a child `.not_special`

Comment: this would refer to .myclass.not_special, I need to style .myclass which doesnt hav a child .not_special

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood your update, so now the answer should work