# SASS / Compass - Overwrite | Delete | Unset Mixins / Include

Tags: include, sass, mixins, compass

I'm trying to set up a mobile-first workflow with SASS and Compass.

Therefore I want to define for the navigation an ul>li horizontal-inline-list via http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/typography/lists/horizontal_list/

I included:

```
nav.mainnav ul {
        @include horizontal-list(1rem);
}
```

Everything is working fine so far. But how can I get rid of this include when I'm targeting my breakpoint for larger screens?

```
@include breakpoint($large){
    nav.mainnav  ul {
        // I want to delete the include here
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this or do I have to override the styles manually?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505378/is-there-any-way-to-unextend-a-class-in-sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, *mobile first* is not your best option.

```
@media (max-width: 20em) { // whatever your desired breakpoint is
    nav.mainnav ul {
        @include horizontal-list(1rem);
    }
}
```

Now you don't need to override the styles.